# Sql Foreign Key Constraint Problems

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Supposed there is table called 'Bill', In the Bill Table, there are 3 columns , ['id', 'client_id', ' client_contact_id'], only 'client_contact_id' **is nullable**.
The client_id will foreign to the table of 'client', and in the table of 'client_contact',
there are 3 columns such that ['id','name','client_id']. How do i supposed to make a integrity of these tables to make sure the data inserted in table 'bill' with 'client_id' is same as the client_contact_id of client_id.

I want to make integrity of bill.client_contact.client_id is same as bill.client_id in mysql.

I have to mentioned that the Client : Bill are 1:n , Client :Client_contact are 1:n also. Client_contact : Bill are 1:n
[image]

Comment: If you cannot have bills without a contract, then I suggest you remove client id from the bills table.

Comment: There is a case with ppl can created a bill with client_id when i created it. But i can update the client_contact_id afterthat. Therefore. client_contact_id can be nullable.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that the Client : Bill are 1:n , Client :Client_contact are 1:n also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreign key constraint with two columns:

```
foreign key (client_id, client_contact_id) references client_contacts(client_id, id)
```

You will need a unique index/constraint on those columns:

```
create unique index client_contacts_2 on client_contacts(client_id, id);
```

This is a bit redundant, but solves your problem without using triggers or stored procedures.  It also allows `NULL` values.  These should be ignored for foreign key relationships.

Comment: What is the purpose of  create unique index client_contacts_2 on client_contacts(client_id, id);?

Comment: And that means I should ignore the foreign key refer from bill.client_id to client.id?
When the bill was created with only client_id , how can i get keep its integrity?

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that the Client : Bill are  1:n , Client :Client_contact are 1:n also.

Comment: @yuk . . . Foreign key constraints should be to unique keys.  The foreign key reference to `client` is optional.  And I don't think there is a problem with the cardinality of the relationships.

Comment: Yes , there should be the case that when i create a bill with client_id only , there is no any constraints to only client_id with the value of client_contact_id is null. It can not ensure the integrity of client_id only.

Comment: @yuk . . . You are right.  For that reason, you want both foreign key constraints.

Comment: Yes , How can i supposed to do that? when  i use composite foreign key with client_id and client_contact_id references to the client_contact table, I can not refer client_id to the table of client table to keep integrity. How can i do both foreign key constraints?

Comment: @yuk . . . It would just be `foreign key (client_id) references clients(id)` -- and that would be in both the `bill` and `client_contact` tables.

Comment: U save me a day, I have no idea that when i foreign composite key to another table and i can also foreign one of the key to another table . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have bills without a contract, then I suggest you remove client id from the bills table.

If you can have bills without a contract, then you need to create before insert and before update triggers on the bills table. These triggers pull the client if from the client contact table if the `client_contact_id` field in the inserted / updated record is not null. Alternatively, you need to handle this in your application logic.

Comment: The client_contact_id in bill can be null right now in these case.

Comment: @yuk and I provided an answer to that scenario as well.